# Get variables value after change

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a script that should be executed after 2 changes.Can somebody help me.this is my script:

```
  var firstname;
  var secondname;

 $('#first_name').live("change", function(){
 firstname=$(this).val();
 })

 $('#second_name').live("change", function(){
 secondname=$(this).val();
 })

 if(firstname != null && secondname != null){
 console.log(firstname);
 console.log(secondname);
 }
```

thank to all of u...

Comment: you need to close your `.live` calls you open them `(` but you never close them with a `)`

Comment: i'm closing them with a ) ...i've just forgot it here...

Answer (score 2):

if you are fine adding variables to the global scope then:

```
var firstname;
var secondname;
var checkName = function() {
    if(firstname != null && secondname != null){
        console.log(firstname);
        console.log(secondname);
    }
}

$('#first_name').live("change", function(){
    firstname=$(this).val();
    checkName();
});

$('#second_name').live("change", function(){
    secondname=$(this).val();
    checkName();
});
```